# How to Xpath and CSSselector for two divs with the same html structure?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have two divs. The requirement is I need to click the "Select Styles" button. I need to find the xpath of the first div and second div by checking the Button text "Select Styles" and then I need to click on it. So how to find the xpath of the divs and click on it.

```html
<div>
<div class="product-wrapper multi-styles">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-image-container">
      <div class="product-label">Women's</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name">Women's</div>
    <button type="button" class="button button--primary">Select Styles</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-wrapper multi-styles">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-image-container">
      <div class="product-label">Men's</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name">Men's</div>
    <button type="button" class="button button--primary">Select Styles</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the two respective buttons (Women/Men), use the following XPath :

```
//div[@class="product-name"][.="Women's"]/following-sibling::button
//div[@class="product-name"][.="Men's"]/following-sibling::button
```

Selenium syntax (with Python) :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-name"][.="Women's"]/following-sibling::button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="product-name"][.="Men's"]/following-sibling::button'))).click()
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```